# accessing database through sharepoint using a service account (windows account)

Tags: authentication, database, impersonation, service-account, connection

I am having an issue with connecting to the database for KHouse through sharepoint.
I have run through several workarounds to get it to work, but to no avail.

We are using several pages that retrieve information from the database.
The database is on a separate server.
In the web.config we have specified the connection string.
We are only allowed to connect to the database with a service account (we are not allowed to use sql server authentication).
Every user should be able to connect using this service account.

This is what we tried:

- using impersonation, where we supply a username and password/ and a connectionstring with Integrated security=sspi/Persist security info=true.
  Integrated Security=SSPI; Persist Security Info=True;

  > this gives us access to the database, but every user is then accessing sharepoint with the service account.
  >   this is not what we need, because every user should be recognised by sharepoint with their own account.
- using connectionstring, where we supply username/password/Integrated security=true/Persist security info=true 
  Trusted_Connection=True;

  > this gives us an error, probably because of the double-hop issue (database on other server):
  >   Error: 18456,
  >   Login failed for user ‘NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON’.
  >   Reason: Token-based server access validation failed with an infrastructure error.
  >   Just to be clear: we are not allowed to give 'NT AUTHORITY\ANONYMOUS LOGON’ access to the database. so we cannot go that route.
- several other configurations of the connectionstring like Trusted_Connection=True etc...

On the database side everything is setup correctly:
- We added the service account as a Login in SQL Server
- The login has access to the right tables with the right permissions

web.config sections we use;
-->

;Initial Catalog=KHouse;Integrated Security=SSPI; Persist Security Info=True;"
providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

Do you have an idea how we can get a connection to the database using the service account, but with users authenticating as themselves in sharepoint?

Answer (score 2):

You have two main options:

- Give the AppPool access to the database and run your database code inside [SPSecurity.RunWithElevatedPrivileges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsecurity.runwithelevatedprivileges.aspx)
- Use Windows impersonation LogonUser around your database code. See section 3. Using Win32 API in [Impersonation in SharePoint : An Extreme Overview](http://extreme-sharepoint.com/2012/05/30/impersonation-elevation-of-privileges/). The big question is then where to store the username/password. It can be:

  - Hardcoded
  - Web.Config
  - Secure Store see [How to use Secure Store Id for Impersonation programmatically](http://www.projectserver2010blog.com/2012/02/how-to-use-secure-store-id-for.html)

Answer (score 1):

If your sql server hosts on another server than sharepoint and you use NTLM-authentication you've got a problem called double hop: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/knowledgecast/archive/2007/01/31/the-double-hop-problem.aspx

To workaround it use Secure Store.